# rendering primefaces chart in inactive tab for export

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jqplot

I've got three primefaces line charts in my 2nd tab of a tabview.  I've got a big "Print to PDF" button above the tabview.  I'm using the exportAsImage feature to pass the chart images to the server so I can cobble together the PDF.

Here's my problem.  When I click the 2nd tab, allowing the charts to render, then "Print to PDF", it works.  If I don't click the 2nd tab and click "Print to PDF" while on the 1st tab, it doesn't.

I've tried setting dynamic to false in the tabview and changing responsive to false in the charts.  Neither worked.  And no, I can't move the 2nd tab to the 1st.

Is there any way to render an inactive tab with charts without clicking it?

Is there some other way to render a chart without showing it?

Comment: you means you need to export both chart to gather in single PDF file?

Comment: Yes, I'm exporting all three charts into the single PDF.

Comment: i have one logic, you can put all chart your globally page in hidden format   when you  click on export button that time you need to convert chart to byte image and bind with your managebean string variable.

Comment: Hiding the charts on the first tab using CSS works, not "rendered", of course.  Of course, this leads to longer loading times.  Another solution would be optimal.